# Avoid IndexError with if statemanet

Tags: python, arrays, try-except, index-error

I have a "matrix" (list of lists) with information for each coordinates. I want to be able to get the neighbors of each element if possible. If not, return None

```
matrix = [ [{"name":"A"},{"name":"B"}],
         [{"name":"C"},{"name":"D"}]]

for ridx, slotRow in enumerate(matrix):
   for cidx, slotData in enumerate(slotRow):
        n ={
            "up": matrix [ridx-1][cidx] if ridx-1 > 0 else None,
            "down": matrix[ridx+1][cidx] if ridx+1 < len(matrix) else None,
            "left": matrix[ridx][cidx-1] if cidx-1 > 0 else None,
            "right": matrix[ridx][cidx+1] if cidex+1 < len(matrix[ridx]) else None
        }
        print(n)
```

Is there a  way to achieve this without getting an IndexError or without having a Try/Except for each neighbour? Up and Left are ok. The index larger than length are the problem

Comment: What is wrong with the way you have done it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check that `ridx-1` and `cidx-1` are greater than *or equal* to 0, as zero is the first valid index. So:

```py
matrix = [[{"name":"A"},{"name":"B"}],
          [{"name":"C"},{"name":"D"}]]

for ridx, slotRow in enumerate(matrix):
    for cidx, slotData in enumerate(slotRow):
        n = {
            "up": matrix [ridx-1][cidx] if ridx-1 >= 0 else None,
            "down": matrix[ridx+1][cidx] if ridx+1 < len(matrix) else None,
            "left": matrix[ridx][cidx-1] if cidx-1 >= 0 else None,
            "right": matrix[ridx][cidx+1] if cidx+1 < len(matrix[ridx]) else None
        }
        print(n)
```

Btw, check the spelling for the last `cidx+1`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works if you rename `cidex+1` into `cidx+1`
also i think you want `>= 0` instead of `> 0`
`if ridx-1 > 0` --> `if ridx-1 >= 0`
or you'll be missing the first index

Solution:

```
matrix = [[{"name":"A"},{"name":"B"}],
          [{"name":"C"},{"name":"D"}]]

for ridx, slotRow in enumerate(matrix):
    for cidx, slotData in enumerate(slotRow):
        n = {
            "up": matrix [ridx-1][cidx] if ridx-1 >= 0 else None,
            "down": matrix[ridx+1][cidx] if ridx+1 < len(matrix) else None,
            "left": matrix[ridx][cidx-1] if cidx-1 >= 0 else None,
            "right": matrix[ridx][cidx+1] if cidx+1 < len(matrix[ridx]) else None
        }
        print(n)
```

Comment: Good answer, but if you include the full code instead of just the changes needed, your answer will be more clear